# Using MySQL functions in PHP PDO prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What's the right way of using a MySQL function while using PHP PDO? The function NOW() gets saved as a string instead of showing the time.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO pdo (namespace, count, teststring) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
// these protect you from injection
$sth->bindParam(1, $_a);
$sth->bindParam(2, $_b);
$sth->bindParam(3, $_c);

$_a = 'Wishy-washy';
$_b = 123;
$_c = 'NOW()'; // Doesn't work. Comes out as the string 'NOW()' (w/o the quotes) and not as a date
```

Comment: will `teststring` always be `NOW()`? If so just put that in the query directly.

Comment: Yes. But for the sake of argument, is it possible to use a function in `bindParam()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not pass functions as the bound params:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO pdo (namespace, count, teststring) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");

$_a = 'Wishy-washy';
$_b = 123;

$sth->execute(array($_a, $_b));
```

Comment: So it's not possible *at all* to pass a function using bindParam?

Comment: @enchance, I don't think so. The functions are parsed when the statement is prepared - not when the data is given. The data isn't interpreted when it's bound - it is just inserted/sent.

Comment: While compiling my pdo statement I was able to just detect the presense of the ( ,which could mean a mysql function and didn't :bind it normally, just used the value as-is: `code`foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
                if (strpos($key,"(")>0) {// you're sending a non-parameter-able  key
                    $w .= " and " . $key . " = " . $value;
                } else { 
                    $w .= " and " .$key. " like :".$key;
                    $a[":".$key] = $value;
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

Why not replace it to something like..

`$_c = date("H:i:s");`

Using the power of the PHP date function?