# PostGisl Pdo prepare-insert: functions quoted

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo, postgis

I have this queries for **prepare**:

```
$query_prep_insert['Prepare'] = 'INSERT INTO schema_125."testalogg" (the_geom, OBJECTID_1) VALUES (?,?),(?,?);';
```

And for **execute**:

```
$query_prep_insert['Insert'] = array(
'ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(\'{"type":"Point","coordinates":[961223.18558917,5745885.0742317]}\'), 3395)',
'1540',
'ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(\'{"type":"Point","coordinates":[961201.163454,5745.5677]}\'), 3395)',
'1541'
);
```

And then, using PDO I send the queries:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare( $query_prep_insert['Prepare'] );
$stmt->execute( $query_prep_insert['Insert'] );
```

I get the **error**:

> PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[XX000]: Internal error: 7 ERRORE:
>   parse error - invalid geometry HINT: "ST" <-- parse error

The **quoting of pdo** is preventing the functions to be interpreted correctly.
There is a way to escape or avoid the quoting of functions?

Ps. I can't make work the solution in:
[Using MySQL functions in PHP PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300766/using-mysql-functions-in-php-pdo-prepared-statements) because I think the values are not correctly joined and I get the error "Datatype mismatch".

Thank you,
Rickyx

Comment: A function is an object, not a value. You can't prepare a query without all objects that are needed for this query.

Comment: So I have to pass all static values with prepare and then execute other queries directly, without prepare?

Comment: Even static values can be put in as values, but all objects (like tables, columns and functions) MUST be prepared before, to generate the query plan. When the query plan is ready, you can tell the database what values to use for this query and execute this query.

Comment: Frank tanks, you saved my week. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Solved: use this for prepare:

```
$query_prep_insert['Prepare'] = 'INSERT INTO schema_125."testalogg" (the_geom, OBJECTID_1) VALUES ( ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON( ? ), 3395), ? );';
```

And just the raw value for execute:

```
$query_prep_insert['Insert'] = array(
'{"type":"Point","coordinates":[961223.18558917,5745885.0742317]}',
'1541'
);
```

Thanks Frank.